# Problems using # (hashtag) in string columns importing CSV in R

Tags: r, csv, import-from-csv

I have hashtags (`#`) in some of my string fields in a CSV file. It looks like that R has problems with it.

```
csv = "A;B;C
n;# 9;0
n;1;0"

read.table(text=csv, header=TRUE, sep=";", encoding="UTF-8")
```

Results in

```
Fehler in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 3 elements
```

The CSV file is generated by Python using the [`csv,QUOTE_MINIMAL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) style. IT means that string fiels are only enclosed with quotes if necessary (e.g. when the string itself contains a quote char). There is no way to change that. So I have to deal with the # on the R side.

Comment: `#` is the default comment character.  Use `read.table(text=csv, header=TRUE, sep=";", encoding="UTF-8", comment.char = "")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read.table` treats hash as comment by default. Change `comment.char` to any other value to change that.

```
read.table(text=csv, header=TRUE, sep=";", encoding="UTF-8", comment.char = '@')

#  A   B C
#1 n # 9 0
#2 n   1 0
```

And that is why you should use `read.csv()` instead of `read.table()`. The first is the latter but with defaults making more sense for CSV files.